# Recording audio from a service without blocking other apps

Tags: android, voice-recording

I'm developing an (experimental) application that delivers beacons (notifications/ads) using "high frequency" (> 17k Hz) sound waves. The app/service itself is functional, but I couldn't figure out a way to continually record the mic input without blocking other apps or getting the service killed by Android when a foreground app like the camera requests mic access. Did anyone try something similar before? I'm starting to think that this might not be feasible with the current Android API.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be impossible to aquire the mic for recording all the time. Instead you could think in terms of a cron job that you schedule every 5 minutes or less, to make sure you get hold of the mic as soon as another app has released the mic.

I use the alertmanager to schedule task like this:

```
Intent newAlarmIntent = new Intent(mContext , AlertService.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 1, newAlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, [SOMEUNIXTIMESTAMP], pendingIntent);
```